# Has anyone had success treating an older dragon's MBD

Tags: diseases, bearded-dragon

I wanted to see if there is any experience in treating an older dragon with MBD.  We just got him a week ago from a friend of a friend who couldn't take care of him anymore.  His eyesight doesn't appear great (they used a red heat lamp) he is dehydrated and underweight.  In the few days we have had him, he has perked up a lot.  His eating is improving, but he is not able to catch crickets.  He doesn't move around great and is pretty small for his age.  We are supplementing with Calcium and Multivitamins and making sure he is getting plenty of UVb.  We are going to the Vet tomorrow for our first Appt. There are no broken bones so far.

Has anyone had success treating MBD in an older dragon.

Comment: Asking for general experiences is not a good fit for this site. Do you have a specific question (what are successful treatments, or how long will treatment take or what will his likely quality of life be with or without treatment, etc)